# Why are guitar fret boards wider at the 12 fret than at the nut?

Tags: electric-guitar, fretboard, guitar-neck, fingerboard

Why are fret boards wider near the bridge and taper of when it gets to the nut? Is this the case with most guitars and if so why.

Just for reference I'm referring to [this](http://www.ibanez.co.jp/products/u_eg_page15.php?year=2015&cat_id=1&series_id=9&data_id=240&color=CL01) guitar that mentions it is 43mm at the nut and 58mm at the last fret.

Comment: This is not really about bass guitars though is the answer the same?

Comment: I guess the answer can be applied for guitars as well

Comment: If you actually read the accepted answer, you'll see it applies to **all stringed instruments** like violins and guitars, etc. Note that one of the biggest reasons (the third one) in the accepted answer becomes more important the higher the string tension is, so classical guitars, for example, can get away with no truss rod and little to no taper due to the much lower stress on the neck.